# Search gridview based on the value typing in textbox?

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am using ASP.NET and C#.This is my code.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="gridSearch" runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:GridView ID="jobcardSearch" runat="server">                     
          <Columns>
             <asp:TemplateField>                
                <HeaderTemplate>                                                
                   <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="First Name"
                   CommandName="sort" CommandArgument="FirstName" 
                   runat="server"></asp:LinkButton>                                                                 
                   <asp:TextBox ID="search" runat="server" Width="70px"></asp:TextBox>
               </HeaderTemplate>
               <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# Eval("FirstName")%>
               </ItemTemplate>
             </asp:TemplateField>       
           </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

So while typing on the textbox, I need to filter the grid then I need to perform this without postback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do it with jQuery or JavaScript instead of using asp.net ajax panel for this. [**This article**](http://www.misfitgeek.com/filtering-an-asp-net-gridview-control-with-jquery/) may help you.

Comment: Thanks.It is working fine.But now i need to search based on the particular column,it is doing for entire row.Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

handle keypress event of textbox using jquery and call jquery function then call webmethod and pass textbox value to the webmethod, then filter tha data from the database according to search text and bind result  to the gridview.

for reference check following link:

http://shibashishdotnetocean.blogspot.in/2012/07/autocomplete-text-using-jquery-and-web.html

you can also use pagemethod in javascript to call webmethod instead of jquery web service call.

in above link only chnaged is that rather than creating web service add **GetAllEmployees** webmethod in your aspx.cs page as it is.

also make EnablePageMethods of ScriptManager  as true.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true" />
```

for pagemethod use followig link:

http://decoding.wordpress.com/2008/11/14/aspnet-how-to-call-a-server-side-method-from-client-side-javascript/